# How can I display a database table list to a URL?

Tags: html, mysql, hyperlink, html-table

We want to display a link of a list from one table in database‘X’.
Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>database connections</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
  $username = "root";
  $password = "mysql";
  $host = "localhost";

  $connector = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)
      or die("Unable to connect");
    echo "Connections are made successfully::";
  $selected = mysql_select_db("nentholbenin", $connector)
    or die("Unable to connect");

  //execute the SQL query and return records
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utilisateurs "); 
  ?>
  <table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Categories</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php 

      $db_result = mysql_query("SELECT Categories FROM utilisateurs"); 
      $result = $db_result; echo '<ul>';

      foreach($array as $index => $db_result){
       echo '<li><a href=".'$db_result['Categories'].'"</a></li>';
       }
       echo '</ul>';
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
 <?php mysql_close($connector); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**I get this error:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$db_result' (T_VARIABLE),
>   expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: dot should be after:    '.$db_result['Categories'].'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot dot before $db_result. 
And you can't directly get the data after executing the query using mysql_query. use mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc

try below code

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>database connections</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php
      $username = "root";
      $password = "mysql";
      $host = "localhost";

      $connector = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)
      or die("Unable to connect");
        echo "Connections are made successfully::";
      $selected = mysql_select_db("nentholbenin", $connector)
      or die("Unable to connect");

      //execute the SQL query and return records
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utilisateurs "); 
      ?>
    <table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Categories</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php

        $db_result = mysql_query("SELECT Categories FROM utilisateurs");
        $result = $db_result; echo '<ul>';

         while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo '<li><a 
 href="/'.$array['Categories'].'">'.$array['Categories'].'</a></li>';
           }
        echo '</ul>';
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php mysql_close($connector); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That work! but the item categories link don't display, only the Label (Categories). What i want to do is to link categories and Sub-categories that connected to a post from the users. So if user choose 'categorie', all the list link within can display.

Comment: @NentholDigital anchor tag wasn't close properly I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <?php 

          $db_result = mysql_query("SELECT Categories FROM utilisateurs"); 
          $result = $db_result; echo '<ul>';

          foreach($array as $index => $db_result){
           echo '<li><a href="'.$db_result['Categories'].'"</a></li>';
           }
           echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank u Sunny! But i get this error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in